# Index duplicate error in pandas when there are no duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a datetime index and then I try to convert it to json using `to_json()` I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='columns'
```

However my index column should have unique values. I tried `df.duplicates()` and got this:

```
time
2018-01-28    False
2018-02-04    False
2018-02-11    False
2018-02-18    False
2018-02-25    False
              ...
2019-12-29    False
2020-01-05    False
2020-01-12    False
2020-01-19     True
2020-01-26    False
Length: 112, dtype: bool
```

You can clearly see that the second to last column is marked as a duplicate when it's not. I also tried `drop_duplicates(keep='last')` but I still got the same error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that **your index has duplicates**, [`Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) eliminates series with **duplicate values** ​​(**values**, **not in index**).

**Your error:**

> *DataFrame **index** must be unique*

Use [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
s.groupby(s.index).first()
```

**for each unique index we select the first value**